# Circle ci workflow job stuck in "created" when adding a required step to the workflow

Tags: circleci-2.0

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_deploy_test:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - develop
      - christest:
          requires:
            - install
          filters:
            branches:
              only: devops-docker-intial
```

With the following workflow a commit to the `devops-docker-intial` branch just results in a workflow that is 'created' - it doesn't proceed further... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that `build` had a branch filter... Even though no error message on additional info is shown...

Hence I needed to add the branch like so:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_deploy_test:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - develop
                - devops-docker-intial
      - christest:
          requires:
            - install
          filters:
            branches:
              only: devops-docker-intial
```